# phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I searched the internet but cannot find anything related to this specific error/table. It pops up when I try to view a table in phpMyAdmin. I am logged in as root and the installation (under ubuntu 13.10) of phpMyAdmin is fresh and untouched so far.

Here is the whole message:

```
SELECT `prefs`
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_table_uiprefs`
WHERE `username` = 'root'
AND `db_name` = 'symfony'
AND `table_name` = 'users'

MySQL reports: #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs' doesn't exist
```

Is the installation just broken or am I missing something?

Comment: I fixed my similar issue in 1 click https://stackoverflow.com/a/66021015/1815624

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You are missing at least one of the phpMyAdmin configuration storage tables, or the configured table name does not match the actual table name.

See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage.

A quick summary of what to do can be:

1. On the shell: `locate create_tables.sql`.
2. import `/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/create_tables.sql.gz` using phpMyAdmin.
3. open `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and edit lines 81-92: change `pma_bookmark` to `pma__bookmark` and so on.

Comment: Ok thank you, I got it to work now. But I wonder why this isn't integrated in the standard installation process of phpmyadmin.

Comment: There is a feature request about this. Note that it will be challenge because some hosting providers only allow one database per user, so the db name cannot always be "phpmyadmin". By the way, is it Ubuntu that created your incomplete config.inc.php?

Comment: The feature request is http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1123/.

Comment: Maybe you should report this to Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that create_tables.sq.gz file can be found in /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/ on Ubuntu.

Comment: I only needed to do the import on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, update must have changed /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Comment: I had to rename the tables too. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Funny thing, after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 (finally) I had to do it the other way around - rename tables in config from pma__* to pma_*.

Comment: I didn't need to rename the table in openSUSE 13.2.

Comment: @Rodrigo no need to restart the apache2 service.

Comment: I got the same error when importing create_tables, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @KarimSamir Did you check both parts of the answer? "You are missing at least one of the phpMyAdmin configuration storage tables, or the configured table name does not match the actual table name."

Comment: For me I just need to create_tables.sql (i downloaded froom github). Then upload the create_tables.sql into the phpmyadmin using Import tool of the phpmyadmin. Then it all works ok.

Answer (score 105):

I came across this same problem on Ubuntu 13.10. I didn't want to hack PHP files, because normally phpMyAdmin works out of the box after installing the package from Ubuntu repositories.
Instead I ran:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

During reconfigure, I said "yes" to reinstalling the phpMyAdmin database. Afterwards, the problem was gone. I have a vague memory of answering "No" to that question at some earlier time, during an install or upgrade. That is probably why the problem occurred in the first place.

Comment: This is simpler solution!

Comment: Best description for the solution! helped in my case on debian fine

Comment: Much easier!! Worked effortlessly.

Comment: Mikkel Does this solution cause any data loss if it's already with some databases and data?

Comment: @itsols, I don't think so, but I won't claim to have 100% knowledge about what exactly happens. As I understand it, the phpMyAdmin database is just the automatically generated database that phpMyAdmin uses to run itself. I am not sure if there are any phpMyAdmin settings or such that would be lost. I did this on a phpMyAdmin installation that I use to inspect several existing MySQL databases. I did not observe any undesired effects.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, saved me.

Answer (score 42):

You just change following line in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$ Cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma_table_uiprefs’;
```

to

```
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['pma__table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma__table_uiprefs’;
```

And restart apache server with command,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This is not the only needed change. but there already is a correct answer since december last year, so whats your point?

Comment: In fact, both answer are usefull. In my case I did what Marc Delisle said but I still got the error message. So I made changes suggested by 
iceberg and it all works now. Thx.

Comment: thanks, in my case the double underscore in ‘pma__table_uiprefs’ was already there, just needed to change the index to `pma__table_uiprefs`

Answer (score 16):

Try  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

To Replace config file /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php with new version

Comment: When doing that you have an option to recreate phpmyadmin database.

Answer (score 8):

I had to change this rows:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
```

add:
    "**pma__**" to ['bookmarktable'] and "**_**" to 'pma_bookmark'

Comment: Strange that the config.sample.inc.php file comes incorrectly without the pma__  in the variable names. Thanks for suggesting this. Finally solved the frustration.

Comment: this worked for me, plus applying the best answer steps

Answer (score 6):

you should reconfigure the phpmyadmin
On terminal:

- sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to fix this.

Edit your /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file.

Find:

```
if (!empty($dbport) || $dbserver != 'localhost') {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $dbport;
    }
```

Add after:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = null; // Apurba
```

Restart your apache service and try.
Hope it helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me ! mine said (on Debian 8.3)       /* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;

Comment: Works for me too! (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with latest Lampp with MariaDB on Ubuntu Server 14.04, and @iceberg's solution worked very well:

> You just change following line in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
>
> ```
> $ Cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma_table_uiprefs’;
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> $ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['pma__table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma__table_uiprefs’;
> ```
>
> And restart apache server with command,
>
> ```
> sudo service apache2 restart
> ```

Lampp **config.inc.php** is located in **/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php** and to make it work, I also needed to change

```
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['tracking'] = ‘pma__tracking’;
```

to

```
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['pma__tracking'] = ‘pma__tracking’;
```

and restart the lampp:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 3):

I use **Windows 7 Xampp's** version of phpmyadmin and none of the above, or below if this post gets upvoted, answers worked. I have tried uninstalling Xampp and upgrading to a higher version, manually changing values in the config folder, importing .sql files from some github page, and even viewing youtube videos but none of the suggestions worked.

**Solution:**

Delete EVERYTHING in the C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin folder > go to https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and download the latest version > extract everything to the C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin folder and your problem is solved.

**^^^^^ Read this if you don't want to waste hours searching Google for tons of failed solutions. It's far simpler too! ^^^^^^**

Comment: Surprisingly enough, this solution works, when I was trying to restore databases from `mysql/data` folder that I salvaged from a crashed HDD.

Comment: Please consider replacing the entire contents of your answer with: "Reinstall phpmyadmin". The personal story of all the trouble you went through does not help others.

Answer (score 3):

Into phpmyadmin database's create that table, there miskta on name of that table it may be `pma_table_uiprefs` and not `pma__table_uiprefs`

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_table_uiprefs` (   `username`
>   varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `table_name`
>   varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `prefs` text NOT NULL,   `last_update`
>   timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`) )
>   COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
>   utf8_bin;

Answer (score 2):

**Steps:**

- Just download create_table.sql from [**GitHub**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/master/sql/create_tables.sql) and save that
  file in your system.
- Then go to your phpMyAdmin.
- And click on Import from upper tab.
- At last select create_table.sql and upload that.

After all it works for me and hopefully work for you.

Answer (score 2):

For Window User >> Just go to localhost phpmyadmin
and just click this button.[session_clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOkLC.png)

Comment: is it only working on windows?

Comment: never try it on Linux or other OS but on Window yes it works

Answer (score 1):

in linux os such as Debian or Ubutu you can simply try this ways, for first time remove phpmyadmin with --purge parameter:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin
```

then install again

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

thats work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the table names as per the error in - **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**

```
$ Cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma_table_uiprefs’;
```

to

```
$ Cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_uiprefs'] = ‘pma__table_uiprefs’;
```

assign the table names accordingly and everything will be fine.

For me,`sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` caused more trouble when I chose the option to **re-install the database**

Answer (score 1):

A really simple solution is to edit **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php** and put

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = '';

It just manages the UI and who needs the UI if its interfering with display of actual data.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cookies

When using PHPMyAdmin configured with multiple databases, one having the phpmyadmin table and another not having it; phpmyadmin will store preferences for the database with the table in your cookies then try to load them with the database that doesn't have the table.

To test, try using an incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

I just located the create_tables.sql, 
saved to my desktop, 
opened phpMyAdmin, 
selected the import tab, 
selected the create_tables.sql,
clicked ok

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on multiple reply here above, there is an error in the config.inc.php shipped, where a "_" is missing, which is what this reply sais.

To fix that, you can add a "pma__table_uiprefs.inc.php" in the "/etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d" folder, leaving main configuration files untouched...

`<?php
    foreach($cfg['Servers'] as $i => $v) {
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with phpMyAdmin after changing Mysql InnoDB setting to
`innodb_file_per_table = 1`
to move InnoDB tables into separate files.

None of the other answers helped in my case, neither `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` nor `importing create_tables.sql`. Both failed.

What helped was making sure no `default-storage-engine`, `default-tmp-storage-engine` and `innodb_file_format` is enforced in my.cnf

After restarting MySQL and removing+reinstalling phpMyAdmin there are no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

Commented out whole config section(/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php):

from:

/* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */

to:

/* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features

I just needed simple acces to data ...
This problem shouldn't be blocking for phpmyadmin displaying tables ...

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu me help  - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu**
STEP 1 : type create_tables.sql phpmyadmin and select the github link
STEP 2 : Download the create_tables.sql file
STEP 3 : Import it on your phpmyadmin using import button on navbar, upload the
file.
CHEERS!! Work is Done!!

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 Solution

Execute the below SQL commands in **SQL** tab : the below commands create new database and setup all missing information you need.

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- SQL Commands to set up the pmadb as described in the documentation.
--
-- This file is meant for use with MySQL 5 and above!
--
-- This script expects the user pma to already be existing. If we would put a
-- line here to create them too many users might just use this script and end
-- up with having the same password for the controluser.
--
-- This user "pma" must be defined in config.inc.php (controluser/controlpass)
--
-- Please don't forget to set up the tablenames in config.inc.php
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Database : `phpmyadmin`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `phpmyadmin`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
USE phpmyadmin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Privileges
--
-- (activate this statement if necessary)
-- GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, ALTER ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO
--    'pma'@localhost;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__bookmark`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__bookmark` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `dbase` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `label` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `query` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
  COMMENT='Bookmarks'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__column_info`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__column_info` (
  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `column_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `mimetype` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `transformation` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `transformation_options` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `input_transformation` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `input_transformation_options` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `db_name` (`db_name`,`table_name`,`column_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Column information for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__history`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__history` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sqlquery` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`,`db`,`table`,`timevalue`)
)
  COMMENT='SQL history for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__pdf_pages`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__pdf_pages` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `page_nr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `page_descr` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`page_nr`),
  KEY `db_name` (`db_name`)
)
  COMMENT='PDF relation pages for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__recent`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__recent` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tables` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='Recently accessed tables'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__favorite`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__favorite` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tables` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='Favorite tables'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__table_uiprefs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_uiprefs` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `prefs` text NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__relation`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__relation` (
  `master_db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `master_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `master_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`master_db`,`master_table`,`master_field`),
  KEY `foreign_field` (`foreign_db`,`foreign_table`)
)
  COMMENT='Relation table'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__table_coords`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_coords` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `pdf_page_number` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `x` float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `y` float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`pdf_page_number`)
)
  COMMENT='Table coordinates for phpMyAdmin PDF output'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__table_info`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_info` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `display_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Table information for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__tracking`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__tracking` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `schema_snapshot` text NOT NULL,
  `schema_sql` text,
  `data_sql` longtext,
  `tracking` set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER TABLE','RENAME TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') default NULL,
  `tracking_active` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`)
)
  COMMENT='Database changes tracking for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__userconfig`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__userconfig` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `config_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='User preferences storage for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__users` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`usergroup`)
)
  COMMENT='Users and their assignments to user groups'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__usergroups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__usergroups` (
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)
)
  COMMENT='User groups with configured menu items'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__navigationhiding`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__navigationhiding` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__savedsearches`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__savedsearches` (
  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `search_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `search_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `u_savedsearches_username_dbname` (`username`,`db_name`,`search_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Saved searches'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__central_columns`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__central_columns` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `col_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `col_length` text,
  `col_collation` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `col_isNull` boolean NOT NULL,
  `col_extra` varchar(255) default '',
  `col_default` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`col_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Central list of columns'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__designer_settings`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__designer_settings` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `settings_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='Settings related to Designer'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma__export_templates`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__export_templates` (
  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `export_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `template_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `template_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `u_user_type_template` (`username`,`export_type`,`template_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Saved export templates'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Source :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/master/sql/create_tables.sql