# phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs doesn't exist using Virtual Machine

Tags: phpmyadmin

I get this error message when trying to browse my new database. "error #1146 Table 'phpmyadmin.pmarecent' doesn't exist"
There are a number of posts suggesting to import create_tables.sql from the examples folder using phpmyadmin. However phpmyadmin does not contain an examples folder.

phpmyadmin is running on a Vagrant virtual machine.

Any help to a confused newbie would be appreciated

Comment: **SEE** Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731487/phpmyadmin-pma-table-uiprefs-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

In older phpMyAdmin versions (for example 3.4.x), the create_tables.sql was located under the scripts folder.