# MySQL error - #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma user config' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to set up my database in MySQL using XAMPP. I am doing this via phpMyAdmin on localhost(Apache is running). The only action on my part is typing in a new, unused, name for a database, click create and...

### this error occurs:

```
Error
SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit


SELECT MAX(version) FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 'stuff_tessss'  AND `table_name` = ''  AND FIND_IN_SET('CREATE DATABASE',tracking) > 0
MySQL said: Documentation
```

### #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine

The database is showing in the list of databases. If you were to click on one, it takes forever and a day to not load.

I've tried researching and implementing the other 1932 error solutions on stack and other places but to no avail.

Here are the following versions for the tech I am utilizing:

- OS X El Capitan - 10.11.1
- Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
- PHP 5.6.15 (i had to reinstall with -intl extensions because CakePHP was complaining about a dependency)
- CakePHP 3.0 (this required installation of Composer to utilize cakePHP from command line, which I believe runs off of PHP)
- mySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.9, for osx10.11 (x86_64)
- XAMPP 5.6.14-4

I've read all sorts of solutions such as run it in Linux, or using an older version of XAMPP, etc. I figured there is a smarter person out there who might know the solution. I mainly had a hard time trying to figure out where to research, as well.

If anyone who could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Solved - Upgraded phpMyAdmin as given here - https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 58):

if someone is still facing this issue, for me it started to occur after I changed my `mysql/data` with `mysql/backup` earlier to solve another issue.

I tried a lot of methods, and finally found the solution was very simple! Just click on this icon(Reset session) after opening PhPMyAdmin(it was loading in my case) just below the logo of PhPMyAdmin. It fixed the issue in one-click!

For me, the error code was #1142

PhpMyAdmin Reset Session

[image: PhpMyAdmin Reset Session]

Comment: welp, it works for me too. I was dropping some tables then this happen

Comment: Finally, a solution to this! Shame I'd already started dropping tables.. I'll copy this answer and thread it from the other similar posts that I found first.

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I find the solution.
We can find there really exists the table 'pma__tracking' when we expand the phpmyadmin database. 
But the system error call on #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine.
So just try to remove the old pma__* database first and reconfig them later.
1.Remove the wrong tables in xampp's installation path and remove all the files in var/mysql/phpmyadmin/, which are similar like pma__bookmark.frm/pma__bookmark.ibd...
2.Reinstall the sql of phpmyadmin, which located in phpmyadmin/sql/, something like 'create_tables.sql', run them with mysql < create_table.sql, etc.
Then it works.

Comment: Could you please give more details? I'm kind of a newbie and I face the same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964892/phpmyadmin-error-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)! However, I really need to keep my data!

Comment: That is solution of this problem!

Comment: Could anyone explain step 2 here in more detail? How do I 'run them with mysql < create_table.sql'?

Comment: @mike_freegan There is a file called create_table.sql somewhere in your xampp stack, find it, copy its content and run it in phpmyadmin's SQL tab. Mine did not work right away, because I needed to delete the folder phpmyadmin from the data folder I moved previously.

Answer (score 4):

In short just replace the content of config.inc.php from line 50-69 with...

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__bookmark'] = 'pma__bookmark';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__relation'] = 'pma__relation';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__history';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__recent'] = 'pma__recent';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__users'] = 'pma__users';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
```

Comment: You saved my day!! +1

Comment: Didn't work for me! It allows me to select the database, but then I get an error #1932 when I try to select the table inside the database. It says it doesn't exist. Plus, I think the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__history';` should be changed to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__history'] = 'pma__history';`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and it occured when changing the `mysql/data` folder to another folder.
I just copied all folders inside `mysql/data` folder to a new location except for  two files.  Those are `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`; those are automatically created when starting the MySQL server.
That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to sometimes the session query may have invalid characters, try clicking on the highlighted icons in PHPMYADMIN, and it will be resolved, because session values resetted to defaults
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az7BV.png)

Comment: This simple trick works very well for me. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

**This is how i solved my problem**

- go to `xampp/mysql/data` directory
- delete all the unwanted files except database folders
- restart the xampp server and go to the dashboard
- click the clear session data icon below the phpmyadmin icon

Answer (score 1):

ErrorCode # 1932
Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__bookmark'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my experience for this problem maybe it could help you :

I copied all **folders and files** inside the `/data` folder to have a backup from my `db` .

When I switched to another Computer's `Xampp` and I started copying **all folders and files** copied before from previous **phpmyadmin** `/data` folder.

So when I was done this problem happened for me  .

To solve this issue :

**1 -** I made a backup from `/data` folder of `phpmyadmin` by copying only only folders have same name with tables I want to make backup .

**2 -**  Uninstall Xampp.

**3 -** Reinstall Xampp .

**4 -** Copy **all folders** Kept in step 1 inside `mysql/data` folder . this folders are only database tables and be careful **don't touch** another file and folder or replace anything when copying.

Answer (score 0):

```
make change in changes in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php    

<?php
    /* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
    /**
     * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
     * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
     *
     * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
     * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
     *
     * @package PhpMyAdmin
     */

    /**
     * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
     * cookie
     */
    $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

    /**
     * Servers configuration
     */
    $i = 0;

    /**
     * First server
     */
    $i++;
    /* Authentication type */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
    /* Server parameters */
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

    /**
     * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
     */

    /* User used to manipulate with storage */
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';



    $cfg['Servers'][1]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['controluser'] = 'pma';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['controlpass'] = '';

    $cfg['Servers'][1]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['history'] = 'pma_history';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][1]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';



    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
    /* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

    /**
     * End of servers configuration
     */

    /**
     * Directories for saving/loading files from server
     */
    $cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
    $cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

    /**
     * Whether to display icons or text or both icons and text in table row
     * action segment. Value can be either of 'icons', 'text' or 'both'.
     * default = 'both'
     */
    //$cfg['RowActionType'] = 'icons';

    /**
     * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
     * button in browse mode or not.
     * default = false
     */
    //$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

    /**
     * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
     * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
     * Possible values: 25, 50, 100, 250, 500
     * default = 25
     */
    //$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

    /**
     * Disallow editing of binary fields
     * valid values are:
     *   false    allow editing
     *   'blob'   allow editing except for BLOB fields
     *   'noblob' disallow editing except for BLOB fields
     *   'all'    disallow editing
     * default = 'blob'
     */
    //$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = false;

    /**
     * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
     * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
     * uncomment the desired line:
     * default = 'en'
     */
    //$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
    //$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

    /**
     * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
     * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
     * default = 1
     */
    //$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

    /**
     * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
     * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
     *
     * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
     * default = false
     */
    //$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

    /**
     * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
     * default = 25
     */
    //$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

    /**
     * Whether or not to query the user before sending the error report to
     * the phpMyAdmin team when a JavaScript error occurs
     *
     * Available options
     * ('ask' | 'always' | 'never')
     * default = 'ask'
     */
    //$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'always';

    /**
     * You can find more configuration options in the documentation
     * in the doc/ folder or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
     */
```

Comment: i modified that config file exactly the way you mentioned, I went through it by uncommenting those lines(they are commented and already there from original setup). I restarted Apache, not sure if that matters, but still getting this error:

`Error
SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit


SELECT MAX(version) FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 'another_new'  AND `table_name` = ''  AND FIND_IN_SET('CREATE DATABASE',tracking) > 0
MySQL said: Documentation

#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in Ubuntu 14 using XAMPP. Here's what I did which worked..

1. Stop mysql if its running in xampp
2. vi /opt/lamp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php (use sudo if you are not the su)
3. replace

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
   ...
   ```

   to

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['pma__relation'] = 'pma__relation';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['pma__userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['pma__table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
   ...
   ```

   basically add pma__ prefix to the left side similar to the right.
4. Run mysql and access localhost/phpmyadmin and click on a db to check if it works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i added those and I added pma__ to 'tracking' key as well. Honestly I've given up on it. I am using Sequel Pro gui and it works seemlessly. I was about to start just doing everything through command line till I came across sequel pro. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem in OSX.
I've tried to replace the things like
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] to  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__usergroups']
...`

It works in safari but still fails in chrome.
But the so called 'work' in safari can get the message that the features which have been modified are not in effect at all.
However, the 'work' means that I can access the dbs listed left.
I think this problem maybe a bug in the new version of XAMPP, since the #1932 problems in google is new and boomed.
You can have a try at an older version of XAMPP instead until the bug is solved.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/5.6.12/
Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If all the solutions above don't work, try to :

Add $i = 1; after /* Servers configuration */

in place of $i = 0 in your phpmyadmin config.inc.php  file

Running XAMPP on local windows server, my mysql data files are not under the usual install path (C:\Xampp), but on another disk.

So now I have the phpmyadmin tables with the double __ like pma__table... and $i = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Everything is for **ibdata1** file. Go to the previous *data folder*.
just copy **ibdata1** from the old location to the new one. After that reset phpmyadmin and empty session .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you need to [download](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/download.html) the previous version, xampp actually present bug in its latest version.

**Good Luck!**