# phpMyAdmin error: Table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed XAMPP today on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to create a new database in phpMyAdmin but received the error

> #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine

So I Googled a bit and I saw I should import `create_tables.sql` located in `/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/example` (if I remember correctly, but I couldn't locate it there, but I did locate it in `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/sql`. So I tried to import it, but I receive the same error.

First I installed XAMPP 5.6.14 / PHP 5.6.14 twice, but no change. Then I installed XAMPP 5.5.30 / PHP 5.5.30, but still no change. I also tried changing the config.inc.php file (then I stop XAMPP and start it again).

Note: I can see the phpmyadmin database and if I expand it I can see that all the tables that are giving problems, do exist:
[image: Error when importing and phpmyadmin database expanded]

I have no idea why this is happening or how to solve it. Can anyone please help?

PS: I have seen that this question has been asked before, but none of the answers I found worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none of the solutions worked for me I did the following:

1. Open Nautilus (Linux's file explorer) with root privileges: `sudo nautlius`.
2. Navigate to the mysql directory: `/opt/lampp/var/mysql`.
3. Delete the phpmyadmin folder. This is the phpmyadmin database in phpMyAdmin
4. Copy the content of the `create_tables.sql` (found at `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/sql`) file to another one on the desktop called `sql.sql`
5. Open the MySQL command line interface: `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -uroot -p`
6. Then in the mysql promp I ran the script to create the database `phpmyadmin` with `source /home/user/Desktop/sql.sql`

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working with some changes in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:

Add a $i=1 after /* server parameters */

/* Server parameters */

$i = 1

AND fix tablespaces of phpMyAdmin as written in

[1932-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist-in-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506495/2364405)

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to run create_tables.sql as pointed in other answers. I added below line after Servers configuration.

```
/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 1;
```

Then I logged out from phpMyAdmin and logged in again. Problems were solved there. Logout seems to be important here.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone get that error while exporting database from Laragon and trys to import anywhere else: make sure you check "create tables" and chose "Insert" in select list before running export

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).