# phpMyAdmin error 1932 - table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

windows 7 - xampp

I have a database with 14 tables. I worked this days with all of them without problems untill this morning.

All tables are ok except table `posts`. When I click on it's name (left menu in phpMyAdmin) I got a message:

`#1932... posts doesnt exist in engine`

On stackoverflow there are six posts with simmilar title, but there is no solution for me.

For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964892/phpmyadmin-error-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine) is about a system table `phpmyadmin.pma` and on ubuntu. I'm on windows and table `posts` is a user table.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin error: Table doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964892/phpmyadmin-error-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)

Comment: @cwallenpoole, no, it's not duplicated. windows vs ubuntu, system table vs user table. I cannot take ubuntu solution.

Comment: There seem to be quite a few answers to very similar questions. Have you tried *all* of them? Then why isn't that information in your post?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me when I was not able to repair the table

`ALTER TABLE Tablename DISCARD TABLESPACE;
 ALTER TABLE Tablename IMPORT TABLESPACE;`

Comment: What if i have many tables that need the same procedure . Is there any way doing this or i have to execute the above queries for each table ?

Comment: Honestly I havnt done it before but a quick google search took me to this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93507/alter-all-tables-discard-tablespace    If the tables are less you can do the answer above otherwise can try the shared link, Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hope it helps .

Comment: When I run that script, I get another error: `#1030 - Got error 194 "Tablespace is missing for a table" from storage engine InnoDB`

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with some changes in `xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`:

Add a `$i=1` after `/* server parameters */`

```
/* Server parameters */

$i = 1
```

AND fix tablespaces of phpMyAdmin as written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506495/2364405

Comment: there is no `/* Server parameters */` line in my `config.inc.php.` Search in notepad++.

Comment: If you dont have "Server parameters" then you must have "Servers configuration"