# xampp phpmyadmin error - #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__userconfig' doesn't exist in engine in New Version of Xampp 7.3.8

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

When I used XAMPP old version 7.1 or below then everything working fine but when I use the latest XAMPP version 7.3.8 in `windows-x64` mode. After setup, then I'm getting the following an error after open phpmyadmin:

`> #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__userconfig' doesn't exist in engine`

Is there I skip something while installing or need extra configuration?

If it can work properly with the current version then please let me know how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin error: Table doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964892/phpmyadmin-error-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)