# MySql stops unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

MySql stops unexpectedly

Here is a copy of Error log:

> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or
>   you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log
>   files. Please refer to
>   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for
>   information about forcing recovery.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note]
>   InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=305]
>   log sequence number 2834539 is in the future! Current system log
>   sequence number 1604011.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your
>   database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace
>   but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to
>   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for
>   information about forcing recovery.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1'
>   size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
>   2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1'
>   size is now 12 MB.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started;
>   log sequence number 1604002; transaction id 1432
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from
>   C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=9] log sequence number
>   2841120 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1604011.
>   2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or
>   you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log
>   files. Please refer to
>   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for
>   information about forcing recovery.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=243] log sequence number
>   2082633 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1604011.
>   2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or
>   you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log
>   files. Please refer to
>   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for
>   information about forcing recovery.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=1, page number=0] log sequence number
>   1608629 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1604011.
>   2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may
>   have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please
>   refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for
>   information about forcing recovery.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=1, page number=1] log sequence number
>   1604111 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1604011.
>   2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or
>   you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log
>   files. Please refer to
>   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for
>   information about forcing recovery.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2019-07-03 13:27:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page

- What can I do to get my database up and running again?
  All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 72):

I have faced the same problem. I just followed the below steps

**Step 1:** Moved(cut/paste) all the files in `C:\xampp\mysql\data` to desired backup location.

**Step 2:** After that copied all the files from `C:\xampp\mysql\backup` to `C:\xampp\mysql\data`

**Step 3:** Restarted mysql and checked the phpmyadmin url, it worked.

**Step 4:** After that stopped mysql and copied **ibdata1** file from backup location to `C:\xampp\mysql\data`

**Step 5:** Restarted mysql

**Step 6:** After that copied all database folders and checked all the tables, It worked.

Comment: Kindly note this is a temporary solution, on my side, this is like 5th time I'm experiencing the error and I have decided to reinstall it. My current xampp is 7.429

Comment: Thanks for your reponse @ovicko. Yes, It is a temporary solution. It is depends on the pointof time the backup done. few cases it will be fixed at first time. Some of the cases this error may repeating. We can use this to get the Database back and then go for the suitable Xampp version

Comment: Afterwards follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839569/mysql-error-1932-table-phpmyadmin-pma-user-config-doesnt-exist-in-engine to avoid cache errors

Comment: Does anybody found any proper solution for this?
even after installing a whole new version (latest) of xampp i am getting the similar kind of error, that too all of sudden

Answer (score 22):

I also faced this issue and searched a lot only one solution worked for me.

Just copy all files from `C:\xampp\mysql\backup` to `C:\xampp\mysql\data`

Make sure to take backup of your data folder to avoid any further problems.

If you see any error related to table engine then you can copy file ibdata1 from your backup data folder to current data folder

Comment: In my case I was getting an error `mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed` so I copied only `mysql` folder from `backup` and pasted inside the `data` folder to resolve my issue

Answer (score 2):

Seems that there is corruption in MySQL log and/or data files, one way to workaround this problem is to start MySQL in recovery mode.
From `my.ini` in windows (or `my.cnf` in Linux) add the following line:
`innodb_force_recovery=1` under `[mysqld]` section then re-start MySQL service.

If the problem persisted, `mysqlcheck` can help, move to the folder where MySQL binaries exist in your machine, and in Command Line execute `./mysqlcheck.exe --all-databases` this will list tables that are corrupted

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score 2):

If your **backup folder doesn't include your latest DB changes** and you are stuck with collation of `in use`, then do this instead:

1. Install another XAMPP instance in new folder;
2. Copy the single folder of: `[old_xampp]/mysql/data/[table_name]/` into `[new_xampp]/mysql/data/`;
3. Copy a file from: `[old_xampp]/mysql/data/ibdata1` to: `[new_xampp]/mysql/data/ibdata1` and replace it;
4. Stop old XAMPP;
5. Run new XAMPP.
6. **DONE!**

All your new table entries should be brought back.

Answer (score 1):

Just Unintall XAMPP and the reinstall it , it will resolve all the issue , but make sure to have the backup of your MYSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve this issue because I had databases that I couldn't just lose it.

**Step 1**: I installed a fresh Xampp. make sure you stop apache/mysql after it started then follow the next steps.
**Step 2**: Made a backup from the "mysql\data" folder: Copy/past "data-org". 
**step 3**: From my old Xampp mysql/data directory, I copied the database folders only. Note: each database will have a folder and I paste the folders inside my new Xampp mysql/data folder.
**step 4**: Copied the "ibdata1" file from my old Xampp mysql/data directory and paste it in the new Xampp mysql/data directory.
**Step 5**: started the new Apache/MySql and made a backup from my databases using phpMyAdmin and stopped Apache/MySql.
**Step 6**: Deleted all the files and folder from my new Xampp mysql/data folder and copied all the files/folders from the data-ORG folder(refer to step 2) and paste them in the new Xampp mysql/data folder.
**Step 7**: Started the new Xampp Apache/MySql and created my databases using phpMyAdmin and imported the sql backups files for each database.
**Step 8**: Tested my applications and they all were working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems like if Mysql has a large database that consumes too much processing power then Windows Defender stops the MySql process.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-defender-in-windows-10-scans-and-blocks/e79012c0-216a-484d-9058-ba741d91bcd5

All you need to do is add **mysqld** and **mysqld.exe** to the process exclusion list.

Also, allow MySql on both your private and public firewall under Windows Defender.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: rename **mysql\data** to **mysql\data.backup**
Step 2: duplicate **mysql\backup** folder to **mysql\data** ( still keep **mysql\backup**)
Step 3: Start mysql -> It is working
Step 4: Stop mysql copy database in **mysql\data.backup** to **mysql\data**
Step 5: Start Mysql. It is done