# Access denied on phpmyadmin using XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I get `Access denied!` when I'm trying to navigate to this URL http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ (using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)).

This happened today. It worked fine yesterday and I didn't change anything in the `xampp` folder since then.

---

Below is my `mysq.log` file output.

```sh
2022-03-21 15:39:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-03-21 15:39:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-03-21 15:39:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-03-21 15:39:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-03-21 15:39:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-03-21 15:39:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-03-21 15:39:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-03-21 15:39:39 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=647, page number=1] log sequence number 3470890319 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 598292042.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=615, page number=1] log sequence number 3339553304 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 598292042.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=618, page number=0] log sequence number 3462892962 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 598292042.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=579, page number=1] log sequence number 3262714642 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 598292042.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=618, page number=1] log sequence number 3462891605 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 598292042.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=616, page number=1] log sequence number 3426045456 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 598292042.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 598292033; transaction id 2595064
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220321 15:39:39
2022-03-21 15:39:39 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

---

Below are my *phpmyadmin* user interface errors.

[image]

Comment: The error message is pretty **clear** here. You're simply providing incorrect credentials. If you still disagree with that, try manually connecting through the MySQL client. `mysql --host=localhost --user=username_here --password=user_password_here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

What I did:

step 1: I've copied to a backup folder all the files from `xampp/mysql/data` (just create a folder on desktop and put the files there)

step 2: Then I uninstalled the XAMPP, and installed again (latest version, my version i think it was from a long time - I think - )

step 3: After that, I've copied to `xampp/mysql/data` the file named `ibdata1` from the backup folder, and also i've copied the folder with my database name (from the backup folder from step 1) to `xampp/mysql/data`

Also, I read the first post on the following problem: [MySql stops unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865620/mysql-stops-unexpectedly) from @Senthilnadhan Ramasamy
I did that a while ago 2-3 times and then it doesn't work anymore, like today, so I had to reinstall and do all the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the problem, It may happen for many reasons. But I would like to suggest you to -

1. Click on config from Xammp control panel beside MySQL.
2. Edit my.ini file
3. You have to write this line **skip-grant-tables** after [mysqld].
4. Change **port=3306** to **port=3307**
5. Open Xammp folder -> PhpMyAdmin .You will see **config.inc.php** file in phpMyAdmin folder. On this file, find **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';**
   and change it with **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3307';**

Save these changes. You can find the port number as follows: Open **Xammp Control Panel->config->service port setting->mySql.**

Now You will be able to access Phpmyadmin.

Comment: It still doesn't work, same error.