# XAMPP phpmyadmin error list Cannot connect: invalid settings, Packets out of order, mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet etc

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I got following errors when I start the server. I did not changed any password or username before stop the xampp and shutdown the computer.

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=68
mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=5140
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=68
mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=5140
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

[image]

---

**Update:**
when I changed the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;` to `false;` now only shows following error

```
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server,
and the server rejected the connection.
You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that 
they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Comment: is mysql still running in the background? or are you trying to connect different machine?

Comment: @BagusTesa It's run in the background. no it's the same machine xampp installed.

Comment: check in the file `xampp\phpMyadmin\config.inc.php`, take a look on the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']`, is it pointing to `127.0.0.1`? if yes, see if you have newly installed firewall/anti virus.

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes it is pointing to 127.0.0.1  I use only windows security and already turned off the firewalls and checked.

Comment: ok, the error message changed.. so.. some progress i guess.. is the `root` still have no password?

Comment: oh, also double check firewall settings, see if `php` somehow blocked there.

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes it is root and no password. how I find the php block in the firewall? I use windows

Comment: If you are facing any error message, please share it in text form

Comment: thats odd, i'm running out of checklist. if the `root` has no password `AllowNoPassword` being `true` is the correct one. anyway, you can open windows firewall following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/open-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security). oh right, is the problem persist after you did some changes to your machine? try to think back what you have done so far before the issue arise.

Comment: oh right, running out of memory can also cause `mysql` to be sluggish and unresponsive. double check how much of ram you have left. and don't forget, try to restart your computer and see if the problem persist. more than often naughty software or driver leaking memory in the background. if that was the case, you gotta fix it first.

Comment: @BagusTesa I will go through the gudie. I installed the day to day updates that include windows defender updates and turned off the computer.

Comment: @BagusTesa I found the solution by reinstall the xampp and add old databases folders to the mysql/data folder. and replaced the ibdata1 file with the old one. but can't able to find real solution and cause.  when observe the sql log files I found the following error ```[ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=243] log sequence number 381975 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 300306.```  in several times. I searched that error and found this thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558617/access-denied-on-phpmyadmin-using-xampp symptoms are same