# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly XAMPP - Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp

I am running xampp on Windows 10. I've never had such an issue with my other websites running on XAMPP. To break down the issue, I am installing clean wordpress I am importing my website with a plugin called All in one WP migration. Once the migration is done I have access to the wp-admin part of the website but when I try to open the website I receive this error:

```
12:48:26 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:48:26 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:48:26 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:48:26 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:48:26 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:48:26 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:48:26 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

As a reference all the other wordpress insllations I have, run perfect and I have no problem opening the websites. When I open phpmyadmin I see this error:

```
#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__userconfig' doesn't exist in engine
```

I have tried all the listed solutions in this thread: [MySQL error - #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma user config' doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839569/mysql-error-1932-table-phpmyadmin-pma-user-config-doesnt-exist-in-engine)

Unfortunately none of them seems to work for me and MySQL still crashing. Is there something else I can try.

When I open the respective database I have in phpmyadmin I see these errors as well

```
SQL query: Copy DocumentationEdit Edit


SELECT MAX(version) FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 'fabb'  AND `table_name` = 'wp_addonlibrary_addons'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine
```

Comment: Could you post A) last 400 lines of your error log and B) complete my.ini? Did MySQL versions change?  If yes, from old version and new version, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# D:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is D:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 4
port= 3306
socket = "D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "D:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "D:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 20M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 20M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
innodb_use_sys_malloc = 1


# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "D:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 200M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 200M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 20M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```