# #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

My question is about Error in SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT `prefs` FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_table_uiprefs` WHERE `username` = 'root' AND `db_name` = 'group' AND `table_name` = 'list'
 LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs' doesn't exist

here it is my `config.inc.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpmyadmin.pma\_table\_uiprefs doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731487/phpmyadmin-pma-table-uiprefs-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 0):

why did you write phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs? is name of your table phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs or pma_table_uiprefs?